# What is oem-wireless-dw1550-1160187-dkms?

Tags: wireless, drivers, 15.10, dell, dkms

I am new to Ubuntu. Can anyone please tell me what `oem-wireless-dw1550-1160187-dkms` package is and what it does? I am always getting the error below whenever I install or upgrade anything.

> `Errors were encountered while processing: oem-wireless-dw1550-1160187-dkms`

When I run `dkms status`:

```
intel-i915-backport-3.8-dkms, 3.8.6.0: added
oem-bt-dw1550, 0.1: added
oem-sdcard-o2micro, 1.0: added
oem-wireless-bluetooth-intel-7260, 3.10.20130828: added
```

The laptop model is Latitude-E7440. 
Thanks.

Comment: Could you open terminal and run  `sudo apt-get install linux-generic dkms` then reboot. See if the problem goes away.

Comment: What does `dkms status` show?

Comment: The status shows: intel-i915-backport-3.8-dkms, 3.8.6.0: added
oem-bt-dw1550, 0.1: added
oem-sdcard-o2micro, 1.0: added
oem-wireless-bluetooth-intel-7260, 3.10.20130828: added

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the BCM4352 aka Dell 1550 WLAN hardware. People running Linux got so frustrated with the driver that the proposed solution is: [rip out the card, buy Intel](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2229472).

Try 16.04 if possible. You need the latest driver to have a chance with it.